How to host prerendered angular pages?
I've prerendered angular app which contains all the index.html pages as per component and module. But when I'm hosting the application and go to some component inside any module it navigates fine and url also looks good, but when I refresh the page from that components it appends / at the end of the url (it is redirecting to myURL/module/component/ from myURL/module/component). How can i fix it, I tried changing basehref in every index.html to match with its path but it didn't work. Also tried adding pathMatch: 'full' property but still it doesn't work. Any idea how to resolve this?
The Angular Webapp is hosted on github pages.

If you are deploying your Angular application to a simple web hosting server via FTP, it’s important to configure the server to ensure that any route within your application falls back to index.html.
Without this configuration, when you refresh a page or navigate directly to a route (e.g., yourdomain.com/about), the server might attempt to find a physical file or directory matching that route, resulting in a 404 error.
To address this, you need to set up a fallback to index.html. In order to do so, read the Angular Documentation
For some reason I couldn't find the examples on how to configure the server in the new Angular Docs, but here is the older docs, which should work fine.

I'm using github pages to host my application, for seo enhancements and indexing of urls, so to make all pages available, I've prerendered the ng application but whenever I refresh the page it adds a / at end of url, making it fallback to index.html is not helping as it defeats the purpose of prerendering for seo purpose. Any idea how I can progeress in this case?

I mentioned in my answer the older docs. In there you can find also the part about github pages. Since you can't configure the server in github pages, you should approach it differently, by redirecting the 404 page to your index.html. Github Docs: Creating a custom 404 page for your GitHub Pages site
